# Object creation using an action List

Tags: c#, delegates, func

Currently I am using using action to append some method call as a string. Like below:

```
var MyAction = new List<Action>();

MyAction.Add(() => this.FunctionA(new string[] { "All" }));
MyAction.Add(() => this.FunctionB(new string[] {"All"}));
MyAction.Add(() => this.FunctionC(new string[] {"-null-"}));
```

and iterating this action to do some run time processing:

```
foreach (var action in LoadDSAction)
{
    action();
}
```

however now I have to call few object creation statements using same approach.
e.g:

```
ClssA objA = new ClsA();
ClssB objB = new ClsB();
ClssC objC = new ClsC();
```

how to add these in to an action so that I can iterate further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your intent, instead of `Action` you need to use delegate which returns some data. E.g. `Func<object>`:

```
var factories = new List<Func<object>>();
factories.Add(() => new ClsA());
factories.Add(() => new ClsB());
factories.Add(() => new ClsC());
```

Then you can create objects in a loop:

```
foreach(var factory in factories)
{
   var obj = factory();
   //
}
```

If ClsA, ClsB, ClsC inherit some base type, you can use that type as Func generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but the same pattern will certainly work i.e.

```
public class ClssA{
    private string id;
    public ClssA(string id)
{
    this.id = id;
    System.Console.WriteLine("I'm {0}", id);
}
```

then

```
MyAction.Add(() => new ClssA("One"));
MyAction.Add(() => new ClssA("Two"));
MyAction.Add(() => new ClssA("Three"));

foreach (var action in MyAction)
{
    action();
}
```

Would instantiate your classes as is evidenced by the output from the constructor:

```
I'm One
I'm Two
I'm Three
```